# Unexpected '\n' in Ruby Fiber

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm trying to wrap my head around multithreading, so I'm playing around with `Fiber`s in Ruby. However, when I try to run my script, it tells me I have an unexpected newline character after my ternary statement. Did I miss something about the syntax, here?

```
timer = Fiber.new do |power|
  power = power.nil? ? 'on' | power 
  start = Time.now 
  loop do 
    if power == 'off'
      now = Time.now
      puts now - start
    end
    power = Fiber.yield
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> power = power.nil? ? 'on' | power

The proper syntax for this is `power = power.nil? ? 'on' : power`, with a colon instead of a pipe.

However you could just write this `power = 'on' if power.nil?`, which is a bit shorter and probably more readable for most people.

Also as a sidenote: is there a paticular reason that you're using `'on'` and `'off'` instead of `true` and `false`?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that right up.

Could I rewrite the line that way? I thought it didn't work that way in Fibers because the first call to `Fiber#resume` supplies the argument to the first assignment of the block variable.